# Give a combinatorial proof for $n^2 = n(n-1)+n$

Tags: combinatorial-proofs

The question is in the title. I have no idea how to do this one. I was trying to rewrite $n^2$ as $\binom {n}{1} \times \binom {n}{1}$. I was going to say the story is, suppose there are $n$ boys and $n$ girls. How many ways there are to pick $1$ boy and $1$ girl, which is the LHS. But then I don't have any idea how to prove the RHS.

Comment: I see it geometrical: are of square equals sum of areas of two rectangles $n\cdot (n-1)$ and $n\cdot 1$.

Comment: I note $n(n-1) = 2 \binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: @zkutch omg that's so clever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have two people that need to choose from $n$ items (not necessarily distinct),

then there are $n \cdot n = n^{2}$ possibilities.

If we instead count the distinct possibilities first we subtract one for the second person's choice, which gives $n(n-1)$.

Note that since we have $n$ items, there are exactly $n$ possibilities where they do choose the same item.

These are independent choices with the union being the first counting method:

i.e. Distinct + Not distinct = Not necessarily distinct.

Hence we add them and get $n^{2}=n(n-1)+n$.

Comment: thank you! I has this thought at first but I denied it for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

One idea: consider counting ordered pairs of integers $(a, b)$ in the range $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. Count the cases $a = b$ and $a \neq b$ separately.